# Why do I get a segmentation fault from my while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, segmentation-fault

I am programming an ADT in c++ using linked lists, and I keep getting a segmentation fault from what appears to be a while loop in one of my functions. I've tried to debug it myself but can't find the source of the fault.

Here is the code in the function:

```
   void remove(int a){
        cout << "remove" << endl;
        node * temp;
        cout << "remove 2" <<endl;
        while(head->number != a){
            cout << "remove 3" << endl;
            head = head->next;
        }
        cout << "remove 4" << endl;
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
```

Head is a normal node, where the variable number in head is an integer. Head itself is a node pointer.

Thanks!

Comment: Well why don't you tell us which cout statement is printed so we know where to start looking

Comment: Hitting a null pointer, I'll bet.

Comment: You never check to see if you hit a null pointer

Comment: `node * temp` what is that about?

Comment: while(head->number != a && head!= NULL)

Comment: @EdHeal: Pointer declaration, I'm guessing.

Comment: And where is head declared and initialised

Comment: `head = head->next` -- Isn't `head` supposed to always point to the first node?  If so, you're changing it here, which is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

As everyone has pointed out in the comments, you need to check if you have reached the end of the list by checking for the value of head.

```
void remove(int a){
    node * temp;
    node *ptr = head;
    /* Keep iterating list if {Conditional 1 - Head is not NULL && Conditional 2 - number not equal to a} */
    while(ptr && ptr->number != a){
        ptr = ptr->next; //Walk the linked list
    }
    /* Do this only if head is not NULL!! */
    if(ptr != NULL) { 
        /* Save head pointer in temp */
        temp = ptr;
        /* Increment head to point to next node in list */ 
        ptr = ptr->next;
        /* Delete original item pointed to by temp */
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

Ideally 'head' always points to a beginning of the list (hence the name head). We usually declare a temporary pointer that points to head before iterating the list.

Answer (score -3):

You have to check that head does not point to null before using number

Comment: You should use his example since he has minimal code, you can simply just say while(head->number != a && head!=NULL)

Comment: @OmidCompSCI The correct way is actually `while(head != nullptr && head->number != a)`

Comment: why isn't NULL acceptable, sorry never used nullptr before, in school they only taught NULL

Comment: The problem is the order of the statements

Comment: In C++11 they introduced `nullptr` for a typesafe way of referencing a null pointer. `NULL` is still allowed, and the preferred option in C, but it’s often treated differently than you expect.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI As Andreas said you need to check for null first.  I just use `nullptr` as I really don't code in C++98/03 anymore.